# How to put images side by side and on top of eachother

Tags: miktex, subfig

I have 20 diagrams and need to put them side by side to minimise the space they take up. Something like this would be ideal:[image]

I have tried something like below to split them into 5 different groups:

```
\begin{center} 
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Pics/h0.pdf}
\centering\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Pics/h1.pdf},
\centering\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Pics/h2.pdf}
\centering\includegraphics[width=100mm]{Pics/h4.pdf}
\caption{stuff.}
\label{markovianitydiagram}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

and so on for the others. Here I am attempting to put the images side by side in two rows and two columns. I am using miktex.

Comment: Welcome. I eddited your tags a bit. In your case, if you only want to imput the figures, maybe subfig etc. will suit you. If you draw the graphs using `pgfplots` etc., then maybe `groupplots` can be the way to go ...

Comment: With 7 row of 3 each you definitely should NOT use [H].  You might be able to fit it into one page using [p],.  I would try putting one row per figure using [htp] and \ContinuedFloat (caption package).  BTW, one \centering is all you need, and the comma serves no purpose.  Putting \hfil between plots will do.  And lose the center environment.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how to pack 21 images over two pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subcaption}% \ContinuedFloat only needed if subcaptions are used
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 1
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 2
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 3
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 4
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 5
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 6
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp!]% 7
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{21 Images}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can try `subfig` to align multiple figures side by side.

Here, you can assign the distance between each row and column and also add a caption to each subfigure.

[image: v01]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfig,caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \\ \vspace{0.5cm}       
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \\ \vspace{0.5cm}   
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \\ \vspace{0.5cm}   
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
        \qquad
        \subfloat[subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Also You can easily add `\caption` and and `\label` for every image in future.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```